# Making a NULL value in a MySQL field appear as 0 / N/A

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two mysql table of numbers. (1, NULL, NULL,) (5, NULL, NULL,) etc, in two table called Results1 and Results2
I'm outputting them into a html table in php, and I can't quite figure out how to show the NULL values as something like '0' or 'N/A', instead of empty space. I've tried using the IF statements for MySQL queries but I can't figure it out. Sorry if my English is bad I do not speak it as first language. Thank you for any help.

Comment: `COALESCE(valuecolumn, 0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) in your query to change output to 'N/A' for the NULL values

```
SELECT col1, col2, IFNULL(col3, 'N/A'), col4 FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
....
case when myCol is null then 'N/A' else myCol end as myColCleaned
....
```

or just using coalesce to catch `NULL` values:

```
select
...
coalesce(myCol, 'N/A') as myColCleaned
...
```

Using `CASE` gives you more flexibility as you can replace not just `NULL` but other values if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IFNULL(yourfield, 'n/a') ...
```

Relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Answer (score 0):

You can check by doing a [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT IF(`col` IS NULL, '0', `col`) AS `col` …
SELECT IF(`col` IS NULL, 'N/A', `col`) AS `col`…
```

OR by checking [IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
SELECT IFNULL(`col`, 'N/A') AS `col`…
SELECT IFNULL(`col`, '0') AS `col`…
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a php if statement.

```
if(isset($row['NULL_ROW'])&is_null($row['NULL_ROW']))
{
      echo '0';
}
```

Comment: That's a lot messier than re-writing the value of `$row['NULL_ROW']`.

Answer (score -1):

in table structure you can add default value as 0

Comment: If you want `NULL`, this doesn't help you. It's also really bad where that is an ID reference to another table.